# Angular2 Service pass wrong url

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core

I'm using [Angular2 + .Net Core](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal) and I'm trying to invoke twice same service function using two different API urls.

My function:

app.service.ts

```
getRequests(url: string): Observable<Model> {
    return this.http.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((res: Response) => this.handleError(res));
}
```

home.component.ts

```
this.AppService.getRequests('url/to/first/api').subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)
});

this.AppService.getRequests("another/url/to/second/api").subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

<s>The result is that browser sends two requests, both on the first url (totally ignoring different url)</s>

I'm quite new in Angular2 and I'm not sure if its a product defect or I misusing Angular service.

I tried to copy this function (for second url) with other name but the result was even worse (much worse). 
Application threw error that `this.AppService.getRequestsCopy is not a function`

#### Update

The problem is that app.service.js do not append changes made in app.service.ts. Have to find out why.

Comment: what is the expected url and what is wrong url called updated them to post

Comment: There are two different URL for two different APIs. The problem is that when I build solution and run project I see in browser network debug windows that two request has been send to first url instead of two different URLs

Comment: Are these APIs on the same url (host, domain, port) as the URL where your application loads from or are there differences (except from the path after the port)

Comment: Same host, domain, port. Another contoller, another action.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed app.service.js and app.service.js.map from my solution and everything works fine.